# Integral over the real axis using complex analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

The problem at hand is to compute the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(x+a)^2+b^2}\sqrt{(x-a)^2+b^2}}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are both real numbers. The square roots introduce branch cuts in the complex plan, so we can't simply use the residue theorem. How can I evaluate this integral? Thanks!

Comment: You can try to compute this integral over a keyhole contour (or similar, along the cut) then use the residue theorem... ?

Comment: I think this works, yes! I'll write out a detailed solution when I have more time. Thanks Phoenix!

Answer (score 1):

If for any $a\geq 0$ and $b>0$ we define 
$$ F(a,b)=\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+b^2}\sqrt{(x+a)^2+b^2}} $$
we have $F(0,b)=\frac{\pi}{b}$ and 
$$ F(a,b) = a\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2(x-1)^2+b^2}\sqrt{a^2(x+1)^2+b^2}}=F\left(1,\tfrac{b}{a}\right) $$
for any $a>0$. In such a case, by letting $\lambda=\frac{b}{a}$ we have
$$ F(1,\lambda)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2+2\lambda^2(x^2+1)+\lambda^4}}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2+\lambda^2-1)^2+4\lambda^2}} $$
or
$$ F(1,\lambda)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{[x^2+(\lambda+1)^2]\cdot[x^2+(\lambda-i)^2]}}=\frac{\pi}{2\,\text{AGM}(\lambda+i,\lambda-i)} $$
or (assuming $\lambda>1$)
$$ F(1,\lambda)=\frac{\pi}{2\,\text{AGM}(\lambda,\sqrt{\lambda^2-1})}=\frac{1}{\lambda}\,K\left(\tfrac{1}{\lambda^2}\right)
 $$
where $K$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind and $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$ is the elliptic modulus.
 It follows that $b>a>0$ leads to
$$ F(a,b) = \frac{a}{b}\,K\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks Jack! Very helpful. One question, how did you notice that the integral was related to the AGM?

Comment: @PhysKid: I keep in mind that $K(m)=\frac{\pi}{2\,\text{AGM}(1,\sqrt{1-m})}$ since it is a pretty useful formula for the numerical evaluation of complex integrals, and it also explains the functional relations fulfilled by $K$ in a very simple way.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the first integral, the one over all of the real line?

Comment: @PhysKid: $((x-a)^2+b^2)((x+a)^2+b^2)$ is an even function and a polynomial of degree $4$, hence it can be written as $(x^2+A)(x^2+B)$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2+A)(x^2+B)}}$ is a complete elliptic integral of the first kind / something related to the $\text{AGM}$.